# Show Non-repetitive questions to user in online test application?

Tags: mysql

I create an online test application.in this web application user answers to some question and see the results.i have about 1000 question in my database.but i have a problem.i want show questions that are not seen before by user.is there any solution to show Non-repetitive questions to user?

Comment: What happens after the user has seen all 1000 questions once?

Comment: when user has seen all 1000 questions our jobs done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could create a table that stores the relation between the users and the questions.

When you ask a user a question check if the relation already exists in the table. If it exists, try another question, and if it does not exist store the relation in the table and show him the question.

The table should have at least two fields, user_id and question_id.

Answer (score -1):

Have a status field in your table witha default value of 0, every time user answers a question, flag the corresponding field to 1. When showing your questions, show only those with a status of 0.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i have too many user

Comment: Nothing wrong with too many users. it will work